# Grails plugins getting upgrade and downgrade message for same build

Tags: grails

I have grails rest-client-builder plugin installed in my grails application. 
Earlier I had 1.0.3, but now I changed the version in BuildConfig.groovy to 2.1.1

Now I am getting this following strange message:

```
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [rest-client-builder-1.0.3]. Do you want to upgrade to [rest-client-builder-2.1.1]? [y,n] y
y
.
|Installing zip rest-client-builder-2.1.1.zip...
...
|Installed plugin rest-client-builder-2.1.1
..............You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [rest-client-builder-2.1.1]. Do you want to downgrade to [rest-client-builder-1.0.3]? [y,n]
```

Now My question is why I am getting the message to downgrade to 1.0.3 in the same build?

I suspect this is linked to some strange errors (like unit test framework quitting expectedly which was not happening before the upgrade).

PS: When again putting 1.0.3 version back, I just get the message to downgrade. So I wonder whats wrong when I put the higher version.

Comment: I believe you have already cleaned the app. Can you also try deleting the project dir in `.grails`, if present?

Comment: I am running into the same issue did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Viriato sorry for late response. I tried almost everything, and still getting this issue. Could not find any solution yet. Decided finally to go with it as it does not seem to affect anything in the application.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this will work for you or not but you can run grails depedency-report command and see if there is anything in there that it's needing the older version. If so upgrade that other plugin If that is not the case make sure you do not have any references in BuildConfig to 1.0.3. This is my BuildConfig:

```
 plugins {
        build(":release:3.0.1", ":rest-client-builder:2.1.1", ":tomcat:7.0.54") {
            export = false
        }
        runtime ":console:1.5.4"
        runtime ':db-reverse-engineer:0.5'
        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.16"
        compile ":scaffolding:2.0.3"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
        compile ":jquery-ui:1.10.4"     
        compile ":mail:1.0.7"
        compile ":cache-headers:1.1.7"
        compile ":rest-client-builder:2.1.1"
    }
```

When I had that issue I realized i had the rest-client-builder:1.0.3 listed in the build section and in compile I had the 2.1.1. It was in front of my eyes and I would not see it.

You can also try to do a clean-all. Additionally, delete all the plugins from your .m2 folder at C:\Users\your_user\.m2\repository\org\grails\plugins\rest-client-builder

Then do a grails refresh-dependencies with just the 2.1.1 version in your BuildConfig. I am running grails version 2.3.11 For earlier than grails 2.3 you are stuck with the earlier version.